# Why does MS Chart only display x-axis labels for some data points?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

When I bind the data to the barchart. I am not able to see the labels in the X-axis for some bars. E.g: i bind four data to the chart. The chart is displaying only 2nd and 4th data label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval.aspx you can try something like :

myArea.AxisX.Interval=1;

where myArea is your main ChartArea

NB : "The Interval property of a major tick mark, grid line or label of the axis has priority over the Interval property setting of the Axis object."